# WebLogic and JMS: Events are produced but not received in time (delayed events)

Tags: jms, weblogic12c

*some tears here* I do not know where to look. We have an application working on WebLogic 12c. The application handles jms events to perform asynchronous task. On average, the time between an event is produced and it is consumed is near 0, but form time to time an event takes even more than one minute to be consumed.

We are completely unable to find a pattern or a reason. As usual, Oracle support ask for a lot of information but they dont have a clue.

Did someone face a similar problem? How did you deal with this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After some research, the problem was solved setting the "number of messages in session" to 1 (default 10).

This value tells the system the number of messages that must be in a "batch" (=session). In our case we have messages that needs 10 minutes or more to be dispatched, so the other 9 messages are executed 10 minutes later.